# OutOfMemory/PermGen Errors Debugging NetBeans Modules

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, rcp, netbeans-plugins

I've been developing a couple of NetBeans 7 modules on OSX with little problem.  However, when I go to debug the modules, it opens up a new NetBeans instance for debugging purposes and after a few minutes of use I get OutOfMemory and PermGen exceptions.  How can I avoid these when debugging?  It's to the point that actually debugging is pointless, and I'm forced to "Run" the code instead.  Where can I increase the memory allocated to NetBeans when debugging?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/. In particular, `–J-XX:MaxPermSize=192m` is worth a try.